# Why can't I publish a comment on a facebook group via graph api since Oct. 18?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-group

I use graph api to publish a comment on a post in a facebook group.
Before October 18, 2017, this method still working normally:

```
POST /v2.10/{object-id}/comments HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
message=This+is+a+test+comment
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/comments

But after October 18, 2017, this method has an error:

> (#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens

It seems that facebook blocked this function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog#v2_10

How can I fix it? Because I need to comment on a post in a facebook group in my system.

Comment: You can't, because Facebook removed that feature - deliberately, it caused to much spam.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to do this via v2.9 API (or below) which is [claimed to be available until July 18, 2019](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.9).  However, in my case, I get the same error with v2.9.  Anyone else having the same problem?  I've been using this API to automatically post follow-up info to my own previous posts.

Comment: I am having the same problem using v3.2.